# ResultReceiver, Broadcast/local Broadcast, Messenger or Eventbus?

Tags: java, android, service

So I'm trying to set up an Intent-service to download data from the internet, and I want the service to send the result object to the activity (or inform the activity that the download process is completed). But I don't know which one of these methods/classes to use. What's the difference between them ?

Comment: I use EventBus, in my opinion, it is better in every way.I am interested in what is the difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, I would use an event bus for service->activity communications (LocalBroadcastManager, Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus). No need to bind, no need for your own Handler, no need for your own Messenger, and greater flexibility.

Beyond that, if you are using binding, just create your own listener interface, no different than how you use an OnClickListener to listen to button clicks. The only change is that you would be raising the event (calling the method on the listener) in addition to receiving the event.

And, there's also ResultReceiver, though I do not see that used nearly so much.